# Date and time Calculator

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I was hoping for some help with something I have been working on.
I have an ASP.NET web form that is trying to be a calculator, now I have dates and days of the week sorted as well as other forms of other parts working.
Now I need to add public holidays to this form.

I have an array holding the dates and if I put a date range of any type I get the full count as if it was counting for a full year.

And the intent is to read the date rage and pick the holidays in said date rage and only show said dates e.g.over two years the count should be double.

I'm sure it's something simple, I'm just not seeing it.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        DisplayDayInfo(new DateTime(2018, 01, 01), new DateTime(2019, 01, 01));

        // Show info for April 2018
        //DisplayDayInfo(new DateTime(2018, 04, 01), new DateTime(2018, 05, 01));
    }

    private static int GetDayCount(IEnumerable<DateTime>dates, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {
        return dates == null ? 0 : dates.Count(date => date.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek);
    }

    private static int GetHoliDayCount(IEnumerable<DateTime> holiday, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {
            DateTime[] holidayState = new DateTime[]
            {
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 26),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 3, 30),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 3, 31),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4, 1),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4, 2),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4, 25),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 5, 7),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 8, 15),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 9, 1),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 25),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 26)
            };

        return holiday == null ? 0 : holidayState.Count(date => date.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek);

    }

    private static void DisplayDayInfo(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        var numDays = toDate.Subtract(fromDate).Days;

        Console.WriteLine("Total number of days from {0} to {1}: {2}\n",fromDate.ToShortDateString(), toDate.ToShortDateString(), numDays);

        var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, numDays).Select(days => fromDate.AddDays(days)).ToArray();

        var holiday = Enumerable.Range(0, numDays).Select(days => fromDate.AddDays(days)).ToArray();


        foreach (DayOfWeek dayOfWeek in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))
        {

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ", dayOfWeek, GetDayCount(dates, dayOfWeek));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("****************************************************");

        foreach (DayOfWeek dayOfWeek in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))
        {

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ", dayOfWeek, GetHoliDayCount(holiday, dayOfWeek));
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/XjoCpf

Any help would be grate, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed some implementation of your methods based on your intent:

```
    private static DateTime? GetHoliDayCount(DateTime holiday)
    {
        DateTime? holidayToReturn = null ;
        DateTime[] holidayState = new DateTime[]
        {
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 26),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 3, 30),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 3, 31),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4, 1),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4, 2),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4, 25),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 5, 7),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 8, 15),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 9, 1),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 25),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 26)
        };

        if (holidayState.Contains(holiday))
        {
            holidayToReturn = holiday;
        }

        return holidayToReturn;

    }
```

Then you need to modify your DisplayDateInfo to loop over the holiday enumerable.

```
 private static void DisplayDayInfo(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        var numDays = toDate.Subtract(fromDate).Days;

        Console.WriteLine("Total number of days from {0} to {1}: {2}\n", fromDate.ToShortDateString(), toDate.ToShortDateString(), numDays);

        var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, numDays).Select(days => fromDate.AddDays(days)).ToArray();

        var holiday = Enumerable.Range(0, numDays).Select(days => fromDate.AddDays(days)).ToArray();

        foreach (DayOfWeek dayOfWeek in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))
        {

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ", dayOfWeek, GetDayCount(dates, dayOfWeek));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("****************************************************");

        foreach (DateTime dayOfWeek in holiday)
        {
            string holidayToWrite = GetHoliDayCount(dayOfWeek).ToString();
            if (holidayToWrite != "")
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ", holidayToWrite);
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Or if you don't want to edit the method signature of your GetHolidayCount method and do no changes in your DisplayDateInfo method, you can do this by comparing your IEnumerable range to the dates in the array, and if an item in the array contains the date in your IEnumerable then add it to the final list.:

[image: Result2]

```
 private static int GetHoliDayCount(IEnumerable<DateTime> holiday, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {

        List<DateTime> days = holiday.ToList(); //convert this to list
        List<DateTime> daysToAdd = new List<DateTime>(); //have a list as container for the holidays after the comparison.
        DateTime[] holidayState = new DateTime[]
        {
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 26),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 3, 30),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 3, 31),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4, 1),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4, 2),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4, 25),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 5, 7),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 8, 15),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 9, 1),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 25),
            new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 26)
        };

        foreach (DateTime day in days)
        {
            if (holidayState.Contains(day))
            {
                daysToAdd.Add(day);
            }
        }

        holiday = daysToAdd;

        return holiday == null ? 0 : holidayState.Count(date => date.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek);

    }
```

You can also use this method if you don't want the instantiation of your holidayState array to be limited to the current year. What this does is that it groups the years in your enumerable and runs the comparison of your holiday enumerable to the array for each year in the grouping:

```
private static int GetHoliDayCount(IEnumerable<DateTime> holiday, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {
        var yearsGroup = holiday.GroupBy(x => x.Year);
        List<DateTime> daysToAdd = new List<DateTime>();
        DateTime[] holidayState = null;

        foreach (var year in yearsGroup)
        {
            List<DateTime> days = holiday.Where(x => x.Year == Convert.ToInt32(year.Key)).ToList();

            holidayState = new DateTime[]
              {
            new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year.Key), 1, 1),
            new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year.Key), 1, 26),
            new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year.Key), 3, 30),
            new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year.Key), 3, 31),
            new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year.Key), 4, 1),
            new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year.Key), 4, 2),
            new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year.Key), 4, 25),
            new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year.Key), 5, 7),
            new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year.Key), 8, 15),
            new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year.Key), 9, 1),
            new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year.Key), 12, 25),
            new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year.Key), 12, 26)
                  };

            foreach (DateTime day in days)
            {
                if (holidayState.Contains(day))
                {
                    daysToAdd.Add(day);
                }
            }

        }
        holiday = daysToAdd;           
        return holiday == null ? 0 : holidayState.Count(date => date.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek);
    }
```

UPDATE: Using my first implementation stated above, I was able to get all dates for a given range (say 6 months). I don't know if this is what you need.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very helpful. however, I feel I did not explain my question as clearly as I should have. The results that I'm looking for is when a user was to put a date range for let's say 2 years they would get returned double the amount of days, or if the user put's in only 6 months they would only get the holidays in that 6 month period. again thanks for your help